# SQL mirroring Error- SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-mirroring

I am trying to configure SQL Server mirroring and I am getting the following error:

```
The server network address "TCP://santosh-PC:5023" can not be reached or does not exist. Check the network address name and that the ports for the local and remote endpoints are operational. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider).

Program Location: 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection sqlCommands, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries, Boolean includeDbContext)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.AlterImplFinish(StringCollection alterQuery, ScriptingOptions so)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.AlterImplWorker()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.AlterImpl()
```

Could you kindly let me know, what is wrong?

Comment: It would help if you post the process that got you to this error.  Were you using the wiard or setting this up by hand.  Is there a FQDN for the sentosh-PC?  Have you adjust Windows Firewall?  There are so many ways for this error to be thrown that attempting to help you without knowing what you have done is counter-productive.

Comment: It includes a .NET stack dump, it's a message from SSMS based on the modules in the dump.

Answer (score 0):

You really should give more information, when do you get the error, what was you procedure in setting up the mirroring, what have you tried in order to resolve the error? However, I do remember getting a network related error like the one you get when I had forgotten to restore the log backup on the secondary server, or maybe missed the WITH NORECOVERY when restoring.

Also read Graham Kents post here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/grahamk/archive/2008/12/08/database-mirroring-error-1418-troubleshooter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have the end points created, they aren't started or there is a firewall preventing connectivity to the endpoint.